# How can i use QtQuick just for UI implementation of my C#.Net project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, qml, qt-quick

I am trying to develop an commercial application using .Net 4.5 because of it's great features like Entity Framework (an ORM with very useful designer).
But for implementing UI, I like to use QML/QtQuick2.0 not XAML/WPF. Have you any idea for this purpose?

Thanks a lot

Comment: One idea would be to write a web api to expose the methods. Downside is you lose the integration between both UI and backend (binding, signals).